# Goodness of fit that smooths/tolerates artificial bumps

Tags: goodness-of-fit, negative-binomial-distribution, social-science

Say we are conducting a social science experiment involving people answering questions such as how many times have you done this or that over the last 6 months. As they probably don't remember an accurate number, when the answer is beyond 10 they are going to be more inclined to answer multiples of 5. This is going to result in artificial bumps in a data count distribution that really is negative binomial but in the end does not appear this way.

Are there known methods to smooth things out? Are there conditions where this phenomenon is not really a problem when conducting a negative binomial regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that I consider relatively acceptable, so I'll share it here.

1. Isolate the chunk of data that needs to be smoothed (you don't want to touch the count of 0, 1, 2, etc. for instance as these are probably pretty accurate).
2. Then replace each count $n_i$ by the average of the counts, say, $n_{i-2}, n_{i-1}, n_{i}, n_{i+1}, n_{i+2}$. This has the property of spreading the bumps around \underline{while keeping constant the total count}. If you want to spread more (e.g. if the people answered only multiples of 10) then pick more neighbours of $n_i$ (e.g. the $9$ nearest neighbours instead of just $5$).